# inner join with max not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table and i am try to increase the ref column value with the following query.

```
orderid name age address ref
1       A    22  a1      1
2       B    21  b1      0

update table1
set ref = 
'(SELECT (MAX(ref) + 1) AS max_ref FROM table1)'
where name= 'B'
```

But it always set to 0 instead if 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you really quoting the expression? I don't know MySQL, but this seems really strange (and it should not be done in any other DBMS)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html):

> Currently, you cannot update a table
>   and select from the same table in a
>   subquery.

However it's easy to bypass:

```
UPDATE table1
SET ref = (
    SELECT m.max_ref FROM (
        SELECT (max(ref) + 1) AS max_ref FROM table1) m)
WHERE name= 'B'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting the integer column `ref` to a string containing a SQL statement:

```
set ref = '(SELECT (MAX(ref) + 1) AS max_ref FROM table1)'
```

When MySQL tries to convert that string to an integer, it ends up with 0.

The right way is to omit the `''` quotes, which leaves you at a new problem: MySQL doesn't allow you to update and select from the same table.  You'll find a solution for that in both other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
UPDATE `table1`
SET `ref` = (
        SELECT `cur_ref` FROM(
                SELECT MAX(`ref`)+1 `cur_ref` FROM `table1`
        ) `calc_table`
) WHERE `name` = 'B'
```